# How to program GUI for serial Port

Tags: gui

I have a microchip and want to communicate via a GUI with it.
I have Ubuntu.
First step would be just having buttons that send some data via serial port.
Because I get tired writing all that commands.

I hope u understand what I mean :)

---

**Update:**

GTK looks nice
I am trying to use https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/linux-serial-ports-using-c-cpp/
also.

Hmm  it still gives an error if I have my Arduino IDE open and want to watch what I receive...

```
testError 16 from open: Device or resource busy
Error 9 from tcgetattr: Bad file descriptor
Error 9 from tcsetattr: Bad file descriptor
```

```
// copied from https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html
//https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/linux-serial-ports-using-c-cpp/
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // Contains file controls like O_RDWR
#include <errno.h> // Error integer and strerror() function
#include <termios.h> // Contains POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <unistd.h> // write(), read(), close()


static void print_hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
  g_print("Hello World\n");
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
//
  button_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button_box);
  int test = 2;
  char a[] = "hellox world";
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label(a);
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy),
                           window);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(button_box), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  printf("test");
  // serial port
  int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR); // e.g. arduino
// Check for errors
if (serial_port < 0) {
    printf("Error %i from open: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
// Create new termios struct, we call it 'tty' for convention
// No need for "= {0}" at the end as we'll immediately write the existing
// config to this struct
struct termios tty;
// Read in existing settings, and handle any error
// NOTE: This is important! POSIX states that the struct passed to tcsetattr()
// must have been initialized with a call to tcgetattr() overwise behaviour
// is undefined
if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
struct termios {
    tcflag_t c_iflag;       /* input mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_oflag;       /* output mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_cflag;       /* control mode flags */
    tcflag_t c_lflag;       /* local mode flags */
    cc_t c_line;            /* line discipline */
    cc_t c_cc[NCCS];        /* control characters */
};

tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Clear parity bit, disabling parity (most common)
//tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;  // Set parity bit, enabling parity
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // Clear stop field, only one stop bit used in communication (most common)

tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 bits per byte (most common)
tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable RTS/CTS hardware flow control (most common)

tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines (CLOCAL = 1)

tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;

tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG; // Disable interpretation of INTR, QUIT and SUSP
tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Turn off s/w flow ctrl
tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL); // Disable any special handling of received bytes


tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // Prevent special interpretation of output bytes (e.g. newline chars)
tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 10;    // Wait for up to 1s (10 deciseconds), returning as soon as any data is received.
tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
// Set in/out baud rate to be 9600
cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);

char read_buf [256];
  if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      //return 1;
  }

   // Write to serial port
  unsigned char msg[] = { 'J', 'A', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\r' };
  for (int i = 0; i< 200; i ++){
  write(serial_port, msg, sizeof(msg));}
// Read bytes. The behaviour of read() (e.g. does it block?,
// how long does it block for?) depends on the configuration
// settings above, specifically VMIN and VTIME
// int n = read(serial_port, &read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
//   if (n < 0) {
//       printf("Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));
//       //return 1;
//   }
//     printf("Read %i bytes. Received message: %s", n, read_buf);

 

  close(serial_port);

//--------

  app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: The `screen` program can be connected to the serial port. You will need to be a member of the `dialout` group (check with `id`, fix with [ `sudo adduser $USER dialout`, logout and login ]. Read `man screen id adduser`.

Comment: can you explain quick what you mean? It sounds really confusing I am not that into it xD

Comment: UTBLT! (Using Tool Before Learning Tool) (Using Thing Before Learning Thing). Do you understand the Unix/Linux protection model? Do you understand the  `man` command? Do you know how linux devices work? Do you want a condensed Linux course?

Comment: Hi thank you. I only know that there are some user groups with different rights. chmod 777 . always helps me xD I never use the man command, only if I already understand what the tool does roughly. It is also in english which is more complicated for me. I definitly need a condensed Linux course.

Comment: "never use the `man` command"? You're doomed to a life filled with ignorance and its consequences. AskUbuntu is a Question & Answer site, not a tutorial site. You can change Ubuntu to output in other languages, begin by reading `man locale`.

Comment: I should really get connected with the man. I will write a page by  myself to get a better feeling.